# Tabel Calendar won't display event on last day of any month

Tags: flutter, events, calendar

I'm new here. I have a problem with the Calendar Table when updating from Firebase, on every last day of the month, eg: February 29, March 30, etc. Tabel Calendar does not display my events ( in the list tile), but saves them in the Firebase database (cloud database).
What is the error? is there any calendar function to enable this?
I kept searching on the net, but I couldn't find anything, that's why I turned to this help. I tried to add events on other days and it works ok. but on the last day of the month, the calendar does not display it.

```
 ..._getEventsForTheDay(_selectedDay).map(
        (event) => Card(
          child: ListTile(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            title: Text(
              event.title,
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              event.date.toString(),
            ),
            tileColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 206, 171),
            onTap: () {},
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Could you attach the code for fetching the event list?

Comment: ..._getEventsForTheDay(_selectedDay).map(
            (event) => Card(
              child: ListTile(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                title: Text(
                  event.title,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  event.date.toString(),
                ),
                tileColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 206, 171),
                onTap: () {},
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              ),
            ),
          ),

Comment: List _getEventsForTheDay(DateTime day) {
    return _events[day] ?? [];
  }

Comment: _loadFirestoreEvents() async {
    final firstDay = DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month, 1);
    final lastDay = DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month + 1, 0);
    _events = {};

Comment: Sorry that i send u the code like this, but i didn't understand how i have to do it....I'm new in this field and also in programing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's hard to grasp the overall flow with the code you've attached. However, I'm curious about the type of `_events`. Have you checked the length of `_events`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put the code here, but i dont know how. sorry :(

```
_loadFirestoreEvents() async {
         final firstDay = DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month, 1);
         final lastDay = DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month + 1, 0);
         _events = {};
 


     final snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('events')
         .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: firstDay)
         .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: lastDay)
         .withConverter(
             fromFirestore: Event.fromFirestore,
             toFirestore: (event, options) => event.toFirestore())
         .get();
     for (var doc in snap.docs) {
       final event = doc.data();
       final day =
           DateTime.utc(event.date.year, event.date.month, event.date.day);
       if (_events[day] == null) {
         _events[day] = [];
       }
       _events[day]!.add(event);
     }
     setState(() {});
   }
 
  @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
     _firstDay = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1000));
     _lastDay = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1000));
     _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
     _events = LinkedHashMap(
       equals: isSameDay,
       hashCode: getHashCode,
     );
     _loadFirestoreEvents();
   
      _loadFirestoreEvents() async {
     final firstDay = DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month, 1);
     final lastDay = DateTime(_focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month + 1, 0);
     _events = {};
 
    final snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('events')
        .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: firstDay)
         .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: lastDay)
         .withConverter(
            fromFirestore: Event.fromFirestore,
             toFirestore: (event, options) => event.toFirestore())
        .get();
     for (var doc in snap.docs) {
       final event = doc.data();
       final day =
           DateTime.utc(event.date.year, event.date.month, event.date.day);
       if (_events[day] == null) {
         _events[day] = [];
       }
      _events[day]!.add(event);
     }
     setState(() {});
   }
 
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
     _firstDay = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1000));
    _lastDay = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1000));
     _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _events = LinkedHashMap(
       equals: isSameDay,
       hashCode: getHashCode,
     );
     _loadFirestoreEvents();
   }
```